# References in Perl

Tags: perl, reference

1

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my $array_r = \@array;
print "This is our dereferenced array: @{$array_r}\n";
```

**output:**
 This is our dereferenced array: 1 2 3 4 5

2

```
    my$a = 3;
    my$b = 4;
    my$c = 5;
    my@refs = \($a,$b,$c);
    my$refs_r = \@refs;
    print "This is our dereferenced array: @{$refs_r}\n";
```

**output:**
This is our dereferenced array: SCALAR(0x14e6130) SCALAR(0x14e61a8) SCALAR(0x14e6490)

Why these two scripts behaving differently.Is there any thing wrong in my code. Your valuable suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Arrays are not lists. You can't expect arrays and lists to act the same way as each other.

Comment: See also: [Arrays vs. Lists in Perl](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @refs = \($a,$b,$c);
```

is same as

```
my @refs = (\$a,\$b,\$c);
```

while you want

```
my $refs_r = [$a, $b, $c];
```

Check [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).

> Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!

```
@list = (\$a, \@b, \%c);
@list = \($a, @b, %c);  # same thing!
```

Comment: Can you rewrite my script..please

Comment: okay its work fine,using reference we cant achieve  my output?

Comment: can you tell same thing with hash?